# ArrayAdapter is null outside onActivityCreated in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment that uses a custom ArrayAdapter to populate a listview. This works fine. But when I try to add a new listitem to the listview with "exerciseSetsItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" I can't, for some reason everything outside of onActivityCreated() is null.

```
public class SingleExListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    ArrayList<ExerciseSetsRecord> sets= new ArrayList<ExerciseSetsRecord>();
    public ExerciseSetsItemAdapter exerciseSetsItemAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_exercise, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle sa)
    {
        Log.d("Tag1", "ONCREATE!!!!");
        super.onCreate(sa);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ExerciseSetsRecord exerciseSetsRecord1 = new ExerciseSetsRecord(1, 0, 0);
        sets.add(exerciseSetsRecord1);
        ExerciseSetsRecord exerciseSetsRecord2 = new ExerciseSetsRecord(2, 0, 0);
        sets.add(exerciseSetsRecord2);
        ExerciseSetsRecord exerciseSetsRecord3 = new ExerciseSetsRecord(3, 0, 0);
        sets.add(exerciseSetsRecord3);

        exerciseSetsItemAdapter = new ExerciseSetsItemAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sets);

        setListAdapter(exerciseSetsItemAdapter);


        Log.d("Tag1", "onActivitycreated: " + exerciseSetsItemAdapter);


        Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(getListView());

    }


    public void addSet(){

        Log.d("Tag1", "onClick Fragment" + exerciseSetsItemAdapter + " sets " + sets);

        ExerciseSetsRecord exerciseSetsRecord4 = new ExerciseSetsRecord(1, 0, 0);
        sets.add(exerciseSetsRecord4);

//      exerciseSetsItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

logcat onCreate:
07-05 12:37:44.855: DEBUG/Tag1(18853): onCreate singleexlistfrag SingleExListFragment{4171f760} 
07-05 12:37:44.865: DEBUG/Tag1(18853): ONCREATE!!!!
07-05 12:37:44.875: DEBUG/Tag1(18853): onActivitycreated: com.example.ExerciseSetsItemAdapter@416f1bf0

first is when fragment is created in fragmentactivity, last is onActivityCreated in that Fragment.

Button click:
07-05 12:38:58.070: DEBUG/Tag1(18853): addClickHandlerSingleExListFragment{4171f760}
07-05 12:38:58.070: DEBUG/Tag1(18853): onClick Fragmentnull sets []

first is the onclick method in the activity
Second is the method addSet in the Fragment. Now, as you can see, my ArrayAdapter is null, as well as my ArrayList.

What's wrong here???

Edit @ Goofyahead: 
AddSet() is called in the ListFragments FragmentActivity:

```
public void addClickHandler(View target){

        Log.d("Tag1", "addClickHandler" +singleExListFragment);
        singleExListFragment.addSet();
    }
```

There is a OnClick in the xml.

The Fragment is instantiated in the FragmentActivity like this :

SingleExListFragment singleExListFragment;

...

```
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("exercises").setIndicator("Exercise"),
            singleExListFragment.getClass(), null);
```

Everything works as expected, except that sets and ExerciseItemAdapter are null in "AddSet".

Comment: Where are you calling addSet()? and how are you retrieving the Fragment? with findFragmentByid?  Can you post that calls?

Comment: I Edited my question to add this info. As we can see in the Logcat it seems like the right fragment object is called from FragmentActivity, so Im stumped..